# Error while installing geckodriver in Protractor - npm install --save geckodriver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor, geckodriver

I have listed the current npm version installed in my system and the error which occurs when i try to install geckodriver.I read [npm module version] - [geckodriver version]
1.10.x - geckodriver 0.19.1 in geckodriver npm site.It looks i have the 1.10.1 version only installed.Still i face error while installation.Also ran **webdriver-manager update** which unzipps the v0.19.1.zip

Note: I have admin access to the drive.
C:\Users\crk>**npm version**

{ npm: '5.5.1',

ares: '1.10.1-DEV',

http_parser: '2.7.0',

icu: '57.1',

modules: '48',

node: '6.9.2',

openssl: '1.0.2j',

uv: '1.9.1',

v8: '5.1.281.88',

zlib: '1.2.8' }

W:\Wgn\JS_UIAutomation>**npm install --save geckodriver**

> geckodriver@1.10.0 postinstall W:\Wgn\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\geckodriver
>   node index.js

Downloading geckodriver...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.113:443
    at ClientRequest. (W:\Wgn\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\got\index.js:69:21)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'W:\Wgn\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\geckodriver\node_modules'
npm WARN     at Error (native)
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'W:\Wgn\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\geckodriver\node_modules'
npm WARN     at Error (native)
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir

\'W:\Wgn\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\geckodriver\node_modules\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN   path: 'W:\Wgn\JS_UIAutomation\node_modules\geckodriver\node_modules' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! geckodriver@1.10.0 postinstall: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the geckodriver@1.10.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Seems you don't have sufficient permission on W: drive to store the geckodriver. Did you execute the cmd with admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have some permissions needed to do this on `W:` drive.

Try to run the terminal as Administrator and then rerun your command `npm install --save geckodriver`

Comment: I do have admin access to the driver and im able to install other packages successfully. I have tried same using cmd as Administrator as well.Only geckodriver fails in middle of "Downloading geckodriver...." step

Comment: How it fails? What is the error message? Maybe you have some connectivity issues?

Comment: i have given the error in the question. I connect behind proxy and it fails in step downloading geckdriver and says postscript failed